# MS Access Help: How to Create a Button that will open a Form for a specific Record

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've created a very simple database in Access that tracks timelines for work. Each record in my main table can also be viewed in form view which is more user friendly. My main menu shows the entire table timeline so users can scroll through the timeline chronologically.

I want to create a button on the main menu that will take the user to the specific record they are interested in, but in form view. It would be great if there was a button in the table for each record, but that doesn't seem possible.

I was thinking about creating a text box where the user could input the timeline record ID and click a button next to it that would open the form for that specific record. Can anyone walk me through this or offer any other suggestions?

Comment: Ayyy Katie, check this out; http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This should be covered in any MS Access tutorial; it's very basic "How do I edit a record?" information. Have you searched for such a tutorial?

Comment: Here, I [found one for you](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=26537).